# VBA : How to compare values from one column and write in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm having problems comparing the values in column R and getting the row with the smallest number and assign the largest value available in column B and don't know how to do it.

In the screenshoot bellow i have data that i got from the "Tarefas e Tempos" button

http://prntscr.com/hikhix

With this data in the next button "Maqs" i will define the amount of machines that i want to divide the workload In this example i chose 4 machines and this is the output

https://prnt.sc/hikj82

So as you can see the program goes from the largest to the smallest number in column B. This means that machine 1 will always be the one with the highest total, total from machine 2 will be higher than machhine 3 and so on.

My question is how can i make the program do what is doing in this example for column M but in column N find the lowest total in column R and write in that row but in column N the next number.

In this example it should become this

http://prntscr.com/hikpnh

Can somebody help me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() 

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Range("A1").Value = "j"
    Range("B1").Value = "pj"
    Range("E3").Value = "ultima celula em A"
    Range("E4").Value = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("E1").Value = "total tarefas"
    Range("E2").Value = Cells(4, 5).Value - 1

    Columns("A:B").Select                                                       
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal


    Range("L1").Value = "máqs a usar?"                                          
    Dim M As Long
    M = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="N maq?", Type:=1)

    Do While M < 2
    M = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="N maq? ", Type:=1)
    Loop

    If M > Rows.Count Then
        M = Rows.Count
    End If


    Range("F1").Value = "total maqs"
    Range("F2").Value = M
    Range("F3").Value = "colunas a fazer"
    colunasAfazer = Range("E2").Value / Range("F2").Value
    Range("F4").Value = colunasAfazer
    Range("F5").Value = "arredondamento"
    Range("F6").Value = Round(colunasAfazer + 0.44)
    arredondado = Range("F6").Value


    For i = 2 To M + 1                                                        
        Cells(i, 12) = i - 1
    Next i


    contador = 0

    Range("R1").Value = "Total"
    Range("R2").Value = 0
    Range("R3").Value = 0


    Dim j, q As Integer
    For j = 12 To arredondado + 11 
        For i = 2 To M + 1
            q = i - 1

            Range("R" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("M" & i & ":Q" & i))

            If (Cells(i, j)) <> "" Then

                contador = contador + 1

                Cells(i, j + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Large(Columns(2), contador) 

                Range("R" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("M" & i & ":Q" & i))

            End If   
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically your question. The rest is added information.

> I'm having problems comparing the values in column R and getting the row with the smallest number and assign the largest value available in column B and don't know how to do it.

So let me break it down into a few questions:

- **Comparing values in VBA**

  In most VBA excel lookup scenarios you will create a loop to go down the rows of a column to to find values. This is done like so:

  ```
  For row = 1 to Range("'Sheetname'!A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1

  next
  ```

  The Range('Sheetname'!A1).End(xlDown).Row part will goto the bottom most cell of that column that contains data.

  Now using this technique, you can go down and get values. To compare with another column's value, use a loop of similar structure, within this one.

  ```
  For row = 1 to Range("'Sheetname'!A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
      For row2 = 1 to Range("'Sheetname'!B1").End(xlDown).Row - 1

      next
  next
  ```

  Now this makes comparison easy. You could do something like:

  ```
  If Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value = Range("'Sheetname'!B" & row2).value then
  'Do Stuff
  End If
  ```
- **Getting the smallest number in a column**

  You can use a similar method as above to get the smallest number in a column. You use a variable to hold the smallest number. So for example:

  ```
  Dim smallest as integer
  smallest = 10000
  ```

  Put the default value really high initially so that something smaller will always be found then simply loop through comparing:

  ```
  For row = 1 to Range("'Sheetname'!A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
      If Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value < smallest then
          smallest = Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value
      End If
  next
  ```

  In order to get the row with the smallest value, simply modify the above to something like this:

  ```
  Dim smallestrow as integer
  smallestrow = -1

  For row = 1 to Range("'Sheetname'!A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
      If Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value < smallest then
          smallest = Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value
          smallestrow = row
      End If
  next

  If smallestrow = -1 then
      'No row found for some reason
  Else
      'smallest row found at smallestrow
  End If
  ```
- **Getting largest value**

  Identical to the smallest number example just doing the opposite for largest.
- **Assigning values**

  To assign values, anywhere in a loop or outside of one simply do something like so:

  ```
  Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value = "some value"
  ```

  or

  ```
  Range("'Sheetname'!A" & row).value = smallest
  ```

Comment: Greta answer.  Definitely above and beyond the call of duty.  :-)  Hat's off to you.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Thanks. I hope this helps some people who are just getting into VBA and are unsure where to start. The above question seems more like a " I don't really know VBA but found some code online" type which is probably where most people start from.

Comment: @Eric F
Thank you for the time you wasted to answer my doubts and for the detailed answer
I had these 2 lines of code https://prnt.sc/hjfcgb
where it would find the lowest number in the column R and then find the first row that had that exact number
but the output isn´t working and i don't understand why
https://prnt.sc/hjfd4w

Comment: @AlexSilva Sorry but I won't click a link to an unknown site. Try to understand the concepts I presented before looking for more code though. If you have some about those then I can edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Eric F I understood the concepts you talked about and I understand the code that i have. In my newest response the code works well outside of a loop but inside a loop the results aren´t the desired ones.
The links are printscreens using LightShot

Comment: So then try and understand what is happening in the loop. Keep track of each variable and exceptions to cycles in the loop. Add exceptions to help drive to the desired output