# excel macro apply formula if cell is populated

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Here is my excel problem.
I have 3 tabs, 1st has data that is updated every now and then and is changing the number of rows.
tab 2 has a formula, that is used to deduct specific information from tab 1.
tab has a pivot table that uses data from tab 2 to show results.

The problem is that, the formula in tab 2 is copied manually to row 500 in order to assure that it will cover all data fed in tab 1. Thus results in wrong total numbers in the pivot as well as including blanks due to the results from tab 2.

So I need a macro solution that should do the following:
1. count the number of rows populated in tab 1
2. apply the needed formula for each row continuously until it reaches the number of rows in tab 1, also change each row from tab 2 to correspond properly to each row in tab 1.

Example, feed 100 rows in tab 1, apply 100 formulas for each row in tab 2, that correspond to each row in tab 1 with the correct rows (the same as copy the formula for each row).

This will solve my issue by not including blanks in the Pivot hence the total number will always equals the tab 1 totals.

P.S. I've tried to make the Pivot to ignore blanks, 0s, errors etc, but it still counts all rows that I've copied the formula, no mater what it pulls out. So this doesn't work for me.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a script writing service. Please lay out what you tried and where you got stuck with specific questions then someone can help you out

Comment: Unfortunately I use only prepared macros, I don't know how to write it properly, but I have exactly an idea of what I need. Also I can modify ready macros so that they can match, but I have nothing so far.

Comment: Actually looking at your question, this can be achieved without macros. Why not just write one formula in tab 2 that has =if(A2 = "" ,"",your code) so that it stops at the bottom of data

Comment: Otherwise in VBA, Range("'Sheet1'!A1").Formula = "SUM(A2:A3)" is the way you assign a formula to specific cells. (Of course put your own formula instead of sum and change the sheet name and range to your own) Try that out and also take a look at my answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1274128/vba-how-to-compare-values-from-one-column-and-write-in-another/1274157#1274157 to give you some general VBA guidance

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I am using exactly this syntax, the problem is that when the result is "" it actually leaves a blank cell that is picked by the pivot. This is why if you have 100 rows in tab1 and copy this formula in tab2 manually up to say 200 row, the pivot will count them as record simply because there is a formula in and the total in the pivot will be 200, not the actual 100 rows. I will try the VBA :)

Comment: Good luck. If you do have specific VBA questions then feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

What I've learned after analysed the OP, that you have only TWO issues.

1. Count the populated Rows is Tab1.
2. Write & Execute the Formula for every populated rows in Tab2.

For this I would like to show you the entire process which doesn't needs VBA.

**For better understanding I've taken a Smaller Data Range.**

[image]

The first task is to **Count Non-Blank Rows**. For this you can use any of the Formulas.

=COUNTA(A8:B12)

=(ROWS(A8:A12) + ROWS(B8:B12)) - COUNTIF(A8:B12, "")

=ROWS(A8:B12) * COLUMNS(A8:B12)-COUNTBLANK(A8:B12)

**NB:** Count of the Rows you get is **7**. In fact every formula is counting Non-Blank Cells for the Data Range.

If you write,

= CountA(A1:A8) you get **4**.

*Pick the suitable one, **I would prefer the First Set**, the reason is simple. Since you need to populate TAB2 with Formula. And the Formula needs Values in the Data Range, so technically Rows has blank cells, must drop out from the exercise.*

Now the 2nd task, write formula in Tab2.

=IF(AND(Sheet1!A8,Sheet1!B8<>""),Sheet1!A8+Sheet1!B8,"Row has no Data")

Drag the Formula till its required.

*Remember it's a sample formula, replace it with your's.*

**Hope, the Solution is fixing the issue. Drop comment if it differs.**

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Although it make sense, there is the final part I am trying to solve. As you said, "Drag the Formula till its required". And this is where I need the count to come in as a macro and automatically fill the formula as many times the count says. For example, since I need the formula to be applied in another tab, or in !C3, I need it applied exactly as many times as need - 4.